# Linked list not printed

Tags: c++, list

I have written a code that creates a linked list of the size, specified by user and prints it. But I have noticed some strange behavior:

if I implement this algorithm it does print a list properly:

```
struct num

{ int l;
num* p_next; };

void add (int size, num* head) {

    srand (time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i< size; i++) {
    num* newnode = new num;
    newnode->l = rand()%100;
    newnode->p_next = head;
    head = newnode;}

while (head != 0) {
    cout << head->l << endl;
    head = head -> p_next;}
    }


int main () {
    num* head = 0;
    add (10, head);
}
```

But when I want to make a code supposedly more safe by eliminating a memory leak and write the same task as:

```
struct num
{ int l;
num* p_next; };

void add (int size, num* head) {
    srand (time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i< size; i++) {
    num* newnode = new num;
    newnode->l = rand()%100;
    newnode->p_next = head;
    head = newnode;}
    }

int extract (num*head) {
    int n;
    n = head->l;
    head = head->p_next;
    delete head;
    return n;}

void print (num *head) { 
while (head != 0) {
        cout << extract (head) << endl;
}}

int main () {
    num* head = 0;
    add (10, head);
    print (head);
cin.get();
cin.ignore();
}
```

..it does not print anything. I feel that the problem lies in something very small, but I cannot find it. Why it does not print it in second case?

Comment: Only call srand once per program.

Comment: Pass `head` by reference to `add` instead of by value

Comment: I say head is null because of the above comment so your print() checks the null pointer and correctly does nothing.

Comment: Learn how to step through your program with the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `head` is passed by value (yes, pointers can be passed by value) to `add` instead of by reference. When you call `print`, your `head` is not the front of the list (because it wasn't actually modified in `add`, only a copy of it was.)

Try this:

```
void add (int size, num*& head) 
{
   srand (time(0)); //actually move this line to main, don't do it here
   for (int i = 0; i< size; i++) 
   {
      num* newnode = new num;
      newnode->l = rand()%100;
      newnode->p_next = head;
      head = newnode;
  }
}
```

You have a similar problem with `extract` and `print`

**Edit**: Your extract function also improperly deletes memory. Here's a full working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct num
{
   int l=0;
   num* p_next=nullptr;
};

void add (int size, num*& head) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) 
    {
       num* newnode = new num;
       newnode->l = rand()%100;
       newnode->p_next = head;
       head = newnode;
    }
}

int extract (num*& head)
{
    int n;
    n = head->l;
    num* tmp = head;
    head = head->p_next;
    delete tmp;
    return n;
}

void print (num*& head) 
{ 
   while (head != nullptr)
        cout << extract(head) << endl;
}

int main () 
{
    srand (time(0));
    num* head = nullptr;
    add (10, head);
    print (head);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/q4YaVQ)

Answer (score 1):

You need a temporary node.  You need to set the temp to the next node from the head and then delete head.  Then you set head to the temp node.

```
int extract (num*head) 
{
    int n;
    n = head->l;
    num* temp = head->p_next
    delete head;
    head = temp;
    return n;
}
```